# How do I create a MySQL stored proc in ClearDB

Tags: heroku

I want to create a stored proc for MySQL. Seems like a really straightforward thing except that the MySQL provider for Heroku has binary logging and [*insert long description available elsewhere here*] so you cannot create a stored proc.

It just throws:

```
SQL Error (1227): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Is there a way to overcome this and create a stored procedure (without spending the minimum $108 per month for a fun one-off personal application to have some dedicated database server for 4 tables and probably 100 records ever) or am I in the wrong place?

The place being Salesforce SE apparently. Which seems a crazy place for the official "open a ticket" page to throw someone.

Comment: I don't know enough about Heroku's setup to add an answer, regrettably, but you're not in the *wrong* place. Heroku is a salesforce.com product, and we certainly welcome Heroku questions here. You might also want to [contact support](https://www.heroku.com/support), as they can probably give you better assistance, but maybe someone here will have an answer. If you get information from support, feel free to add your own answer, too.